# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>'

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Hi I am using Angular 2 final with router 3.0. I want to filter the events that are emitted from `this.router.events`

What I want to do :

```js
import 'rxjs/operator/filter';

//...

this.router.events
  .filter((event:Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

`event` can be instanceOf `NavigationEnd`, `NavigationStart` or `RoutesRecognized` but I want only `NavigationEnd`. But I get an error that

`Property 'filter' does not exist on type Observable<Event>`

during compile time.

When i import the whole `rxjs` library the error disappears. What should I import to make it work without loading the full rxjs library ?

Comment: Where do you get this error? When doing `tsc` or in the IDE? Some IDE had issues with rxjs imports.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**UPDATE**

For `RXJS 5.x` version:

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';`

For `RXJS 6.x` [version](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#-rxjs-reactive-extensions-for-javascript):

`import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';`

> The [following rules](https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/) have been designed by the RxJS team to help
>   JavaScript developers refactor import paths:
>
> 1. `rxjs/operators`: Contains all pipeable operators.
>
> `import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';`
>
> 2. `rxjs`: Contains creation methods, types, schedulers, and utilities.
>
> `import { Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from,
>   interval, merge, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: Can you please give some inside, why this is necessary? Or a link to an explanation.

Comment: Note that you can add this to test.ts if you - like me - only have this issue with spec tests (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3249)

Comment: > why this is necessary  ....  Looks like this is to make tree-shaking more effective

Comment: And in rxjs > 6, you must not to forget to use pipe function with operators such as filter, map, etc

Answer (score 59):

There are several possible fixes for this scenario.

#### 1) Use pipeable operators

Pipeable operators are meant to be a better approach for pulling in just the operators you need than the "patch" operators found in rxjs/add/operator/*

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ..

 this.router.events.pipe(
   filter((event:Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
 ).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

---

#### 2) Use 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'

Change the import statement to `import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'`. This will modify `Observable.prototype` and add `filter` method to an every instance of the Observable class.

There are two consequences:

- it is enough to execute the import statement just once per the application
- in a shared library/npm package this might bring some confusion to a library consumer (`filter()` method will magically appear under `Observable` while using the library)

---

#### 3) Leave the operator import but change how it is called

The statement `import 'rxjs/operator/filter'` is perfectly valid. It will import just the operator. This approach will not mess with the `Observable.prototype`. On downside it will make it more difficult to chain several operators.

```
import 'rxjs/operator/filter'; // This is valid import statement.
                               // It will import the operator without 
                               // modifying Observable prototype
// ..

// Change how the operator is called
filter.call(
   this.router.events, 
   (event:Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

---

More details: [Pipeable Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)

Comment: Anyone know how to get any of these 3 fixes to work with Angular 8? Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

Angular Update(5.x to 6.x) also comes with update of rxjs from 5.x to 6.x
So simply add

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

then

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((event:Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Hope That helps someone

Comment: This helped, since I really didn't know what to do with the `router.events`.
But then this enlighted me, that `router.events` returns a type of `Observable` and `rxjs` new approach it to `pipe()` everything.
So, thx

Comment: Your welcome @YoracoGonzales the idea of piping everything is still confusing. Glad to help

Answer (score 11):

After updating to Rxjs 6 with Angular 6 upgrade.

```
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

...
this.registrationForm.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        filter(() => this.registrationForm.valid),
        map((registrationForm: any) => {
          this.registrationVm.username = registrationForm.username;
          this.registrationVm.password = registrationForm.password;
          this.registrationVm.passwordConfirm = registrationForm.passwordConfirm;
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
```

Comment: this works for me using angular version 7. Can you explain why `scan` rxjs operator is needed to make filter and map work. It didn't work until I added the scan operator. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to work around that is to just

```
npm install rxjs-compat
```

which will make any version differences magically go away!

Comment: this is a workaround, to ***avoid*** migration. So eventually it is necessary to migrate

Comment: so, its just a workaround never a solution. Your answer should atleast mention that. Lot of newbie may think it as a solution and end up adding an extra package.

Comment: That used be clear from the original question which at the time specified without importing rxjs completely or refactoring the existing code.

Answer (score 2):

**PLEASE NOTE:**

I would like to mention a few things that the above answers are not addressing.

RxJs is a standalone library, and for that matter its operations are standalone methods as well. map, filter etc are operator methods that are not accessed through an object. Remember that you import them seperately.

So for example you cannot `import { filter}` and want to access it through the `router` object. That will never work because a `router` object is an angular specific class instance somewhere in the API's. Angular provides a `pipe()` method that allows you to register methods that must be chained in the process before moving to the next method within the `router` that aren't part of the `router` object.

**ALWAYS REMEMBER THAT**

Comment: I don't fully follow what you are saying, but I think my problem with trying to use 
```
 this.router.events.pipe(
   filter((event:Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
 ).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
``` 
in Angular 8 is related. I get incompatibility errors. How to fix?

Comment: That's the simplest I can put it... Look, Consider RxJS methods like a module consisting of different functions... Those functions are independent themselves and does not require to be accessed through an object... So what I am saying is that RxJS methods are not part of the router object.. but to use them you need to use pipe()... Create a question and show us the error?

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Makes sense. I have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
transform(value: any,  args?: any): unknown {
  if(!args)     
    return value;
  return value.filter(item => item.title)
}

transform(value: any,  args?: any): unknown {
  if(!args)     
    return value;
  return value.filter(item => item.title)
}
```

If show filter error use like this, mainly `value:any` is working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the type of Event here -> **.filter((event:Event)**

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more detailed answer? This will help beginners