# filter in createSelector ngrx with props

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I'm trying to create a simple selector to get all the messages in the store by a `visitor_id`, however, what seems so simple to do is always challenging to achieve in ngrx.

I'm using ngrx entity, so I already have the `selectAll` selector ready, so i tried to do the following:

```ts
export const selectMessagesState = createFeatureSelector<MessagesState>('messages');

export const selectAllMessages =  createSelector(
    selectMessagesState,
    fromMessage.selectAll
);

export const selectMessageByVisitorId = createSelector(
    select(selectAll),
    (visitor_id) => map(val => val.filter(c => c.visitor_id == visitor_id))
);
```

and in the components:

```ts
export class Message {
    id: number;
    message: string;
    visitor_id: number;
    is_from_visitor: boolean;
    created_at: string;
}
public messages$ : Observable<Message[]>;

public showThread(visitor: Visitor){

   this.messages$ = this.store.select(selectMessageByVisitorId({ visitor_id: visitor.id}));
```

However i'm getting `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'unknown'` in `selectMessageByVisitorId`. I'm pretty sure i'm not following the right approach. What I'm trying to do is simple, pass a `visitor id` to the `selectMessageByVisitorId` selectir, where it returns the list of messages in the feature store, filtered by the `visitor_id`.

### Update #1

As per @Nikhil suggestion, I changed the selector to :

```ts
export const selectMessageByVisitorId = ({visitor_id}) => createSelector(
    select(selectAll),
    messages => messages.filter(val => val.visitor_id == visitor_id)
);
```

However I'm getting `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Message[]>`, event though i imported `import { filter} from 'rxjs/operators';` (im using ngrx 8.0).

So I though of trying:

```ts
export const selectMessageByVisitorId = ({visitor_id}) => createSelector(
    select(selectAll),
    messages => messages.pipe(
            map(val => val.filter(c => c.visitor_id == visitor_id)  ) 
        )
);
```

but now im getting `Type 'Observable<Observable<Message[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Message[]>'.` in the component file `this.messages$ = this.store.select(selectMessageByVisitorId({ visitor_id: visitor.id}));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map()` isn't needed here, just use `filter()`.

**Approach 1:**

```
export const selectMessageByVisitorId = ({visitor_id}) => createSelector(   
    pipe(
     select(selectAll),
     filter(val => val.visitor_id == visitor_id)
    )
);
```

**Approach 2:**

```
export const selectAllMessages =  createSelector(
    selectMessagesState,
    fromMessage.selectAll
);

export const selectMessageByVisitorId = ({visitor_id}) => createSelector(
    selectAllMessages,
    messages => messages.filter(val => val.visitor_id == visitor_id)
);
```

Then subscribe to the messages.

```
this.messages$ = this.store.select(
  selectMessageByVisitorId({visitor_id: visitor.id})
);

this.messages$.subscribe((messages) => {
  // Handle response.
  console.log(messages);
});
```

Comment: didnt compile unfortunately, getting `Property 'visitor_id' does not exist on type 'unknown'` on the filter function, also `(visitor_id)` is shown as of type `Observable<Message[]` in vscode intellisense, although it should be a number.

Comment: Based on your `RxJS` version, make sure you import proper module. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39514938/2924577).

Comment: filter was imported, however the problem is in the input `val` to the filter function is assumed to be unknown

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam - Check out my edited answer and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: thanks a lot of helping out, i updated the question, close, but not there yet

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam - I edited my answer with two approaches. Can you try both of them and see if they are working?

Comment: I tried the second approach, but when assigning the observable to the selector in `this.messages$ = this.store.select(selectMessageByVisitorId({ visitor_id: visitor.id}));`, nothing happens and the breakpoints in `createSelector` are not being fired at all

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam - Make sure you subscribe to the messages as shown in my answer.